# I wanted to use DB Name variable while executing the Stored Procedure sys.sp_cdc_enable_table for 100 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is the small part of the logic of an procedure, I'm trying to run sp_cdc_enable_table SP for 100 Tables on the provided Database as variable.

I wanted to pass database name as variable and directly execute the `sp_cdc_enable_table`. If I do it without giving the database name it tries to enable CDC on MASTER Database instead of variable passed database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_SP]  
(  
    @V1 NVARCHAR(100),
    @V2 NVARCHAR(100),
    @DBName NVARCHAR(500)
)
BEGIN

    exec @DBName+.[sys].[sp_cdc_enable_table] @source_schema =  'dbo',  @source_name =  'Sample', @role_name = NULL, @supports_net_changes =  0, @captured_column_list =  '[Code1], [Code2]';

    -- But giving Syntax Error OR

    exec 'ABC_'+@V1+'_'+@V2+'_XYZ'.sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema =  'dbo',  @source_name =  'Category', @role_name = NULL, @supports_net_changes =  0, @captured_column_list =  '[Category1], [Category2]';

    -- But giving Syntax Error
END
```

Expectation

```
--EXEC my_SP @V1= 'TEST', @V2 = 'TEST11',  @DBName= 'ABC_TEST_TEST11_XYZ'
```

I can't use `sp_executesql` because I need to run `sp_cdc_enable_table` SP for 100 Tables with lot many of columns. In that case @Query can't hold all Script. I want it to execute directly like above.

Answer (score 0):

Trying it with DynamicSQL could solve it ?
You can use parameters V1 and V2 by replacing your parameters in the sample code below

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000), @dbName as varchar(50)
SET @dbName = 'db'

SET @SQL = 'exec ' + @DBName + '.[sys].[sp_cdc_enable_table] @source_schema =  ''dbo'',  @source_name =  ''Sample'', @role_name = NULL, @supports_net_changes =  0, @captured_column_list =  ''[Code1], [Code2]'''
PRINT @SQL
EXEC @SQL
```

Comment: This would not work when i have 100 hundreds of table with hundred of column.  DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)  can't hold all the query. And V1 & V2 are variable name. I tried to concate to get Database like exec 'ABC_'+@V1+'_'+@V2+'_AMRIT'.sys.sp_cdc_enable_table. But it is giving Syntax error.

Comment: How long is your query ? You can use 2 SQL parameter and then EXEC(@SQL1 + @SQL2). Will it solve your problem ?

Comment: I'm performing this task not only for one Database but 12 Database, wherein every Database has 10, 50 or 60 Tables(not Fixed) with 10, 25, 35 Column (Not Fixed) inside Else IF logic. I guess using EXEC(@SQL1 + @SQL2) will not work. I'm looking to have solution like  "exec @DBName+.[sys].[sp_cdc_enable_table]..."  OR "exec 'ABC_'+@V1+'_'+@V2+'_AMRIT'.sys.sp_cdc_enable_table" . So that i do not have store it instead i directly execute on Corresponding DB for a table. Hope you get the issue. Please suggest.

Comment: Not sure I really understand what you are trying to do but : Creating a table with all the tables, db and columns that you want to perform and then use a cursor to exec SQL dynamic for each row that you've created in that table would be a solution ?